# pass parameter in mvc4 partial view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I created a partial view with google code and I want to send two parameters to that view.
Here is the content for the partial view:

```
    <!-- Google Code for apply Conversion Page --> <script type="text/javascript">
   /* <![CDATA[ */
   var google_conversion_id = 1234567;
   var google_conversion_language = "en";
   var google_conversion_format = "2";
   var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
   var google_conversion_label = "7df7df7sdfdf"; var google_conversion_value = 0;
   /* ]]> */
   </script>
   <script type="text/javascript"  
   src="https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
   </script>
   <noscript>
   <div style="display:inline;">
   <img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt=""  
   src="https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/1234567/?value=0&amp;label=7df7df7sdfdf&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
   </div>
   </noscript>
```

Now instead of the static value for google_conversion_id and google_conversion_label I want to use two parameters which I'll sent from the main form.

Here is how I call the partial view:

@{ Html.RenderPartial("Google");   }

Any idea how can I achieve that?
Thx, Laziale

Answer (score 1):

You could use RenderAction instead of RenderPartial. Then you can write you own action in the controller and you can add parameters. Something like this:

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("Action", "Controller", new { id = "Something", label = "Label" }); }
```

or you create a new model for the partial view in the code behind.

Another option would be to store the parameters in the ViewBag, but that's more like a hack.

Comment: Do I need to include controller as well? Is that mandatory? Because at this moment I have only partial view. Thanks @slfan

Comment: If you use RenderAction you need a controller. But you might reuse an existing controller and just write a new action for your partial view. If you don't want the controller, you can still store the parameters in the ViewBag. BTW: if you use RenderPartial, you can leave the curly brackets away. Just @Html.RenderPartial